# Knockout Js "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element"

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am using kendo mobile app builder  and I am using knockout js for bindings but I am getting error "**You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element**". I have two javascript file which consist bindings, below my code

```
//Employee.js//

function EmployeeViewModel() {
   this.EmployeeName= ko.observable();
   this.EmployeeMobile= ko.observable();
   this.EmployeeEmail= ko.observable(); }
   ko.applyBindings(new EmployeeViewModel());

//Company.js//
function CompanyViewModel() {
   this.CompanyName= ko.observable();
   this.CompanyMobile= ko.observable();
   this.CompanyEmail= ko.observable(); }
   ko.applyBindings(new CompanyViewModel());

//In index page i am using this both script file drag and drop//
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="Employee.js"></script>
  <script src="Company.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "ko.applyBindings" function takes 2 arguments:

```
applyBindings(viewModelOrBindingContext, rootNode);
```

first - view model

second - DOM node the binding will be applied to

You call "ko.applyBindings" method twice - in both functions, with the first parameter only. This means you are going to bind two different models to the same node - document root. This causes the error.

You can use two approaches:

- create one global view model with submodels and apply binding only once:

  ```
  //Employee.js//
  function EmployeeViewModel() {
     this.EmployeeName= ko.observable();
     this.EmployeeMobile= ko.observable();
     this.EmployeeEmail= ko.observable();
  }

  //Company.js//
  function CompanyViewModel() {
     this.CompanyName= ko.observable();
     this.CompanyMobile= ko.observable();
     this.CompanyEmail= ko.observable();
  }

  //In index page i am using this both script file drag and drop//
  <html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
    <script src="Employee.js"></script>
    <script src="Company.js"></script>
    <script>
     ko.applyBindings({ employee: new EmployeeViewModel(), company: new CompanyViewModel() });
    </script>
   </body>
  </html>
  ```
- apply bindings to different nodes:

```

```
//Employee.js
function EmployeeViewModel() {
   this.EmployeeName= ko.observable();
   this.EmployeeMobile= ko.observable();
   this.EmployeeEmail= ko.observable();
   ko.applyBindings(new EmployeeViewModel(), document.getElementById("employee"));
}

//Company.js
function CompanyViewModel() {
   this.CompanyName= ko.observable();
   this.CompanyMobile= ko.observable();
   this.CompanyEmail= ko.observable();
   ko.applyBindings(new CompanyViewModel(), document.getElementById("company"));
}

//In index page i am using this both script file drag and drop//
<html>
 <body>
  <script src="Employee.js"></script>
  <script src="Company.js"></script>
  <div id="employee"></div>
  <div id="company"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

```

Answer (score 2):

To apply binding multiple time. You need to first clear the binding.

like below

```
var element = $('#elementId')[0]; 
ko.cleanNode(element);
```

Then only you can apply binding again on same element.

Comment: What does this do? To me it sounds like you remove the binding, meaning you will not have it multiple times..